# why does low power wifi still burst at high power

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I had set some wifi devices to low power (10mW), with txpower tweaks. Like a smartphone, tablet and AP (with iwconfig, wl txpwr and nvram tweaks).

That works for the general power that they put out, though I found that all of them occasionaly, every couple of seconds, transmit at the original power level (100mW).

Why is that, can I make them totally low power?

The bridged AP is an ASUS RT-AC1200G+, Wifi AC, 2.4 5Ghz. There are hundreds of clients on the network that consists of many APs.
So there is a lot of idle network traffic, like MDNS, SSDP and ARP.
So I can measure easily.

EDIT: Solution: I found that for the bridged AP, the right command in a ssh shell for lowest power output is: wl -i ethX txpwr X. There are 2 radio devices and they both need to be set. My eth devices are eth1 and eth2

Comment: Try setting up Wireshark while you are measuring the high power burst, the only thing I can think of is maybe Management frames are exempt from the tx settings because of the hidden node problem.

Comment: 100 milliWatts is the default maximum wifi transmitting power in many countries. Equals to 20 dBm.

Comment: I found the solution for the bridged AP, the right command is: wl -i ethX txpwr X. There are 2 radio devices and they both need to be set. My eth devices are eth1 and eth2.

Comment: Added to the AP Autostart with an USB thumbdrive. admin@RT-AC1200G+:/tmp/home/root# nvram show| grep mount
size: 40778 bytes (24758 left)
usb_automount=1
apps_mounted_path=
script_usbmount=/usr/sbin/wl -a eth1 txpwr1 1 && /usr/sbin/wl -a eth2 txpwr1 1
script_usbumount=

Comment: What dbi are the antennas? Is this factory firmware or third party? And again, how are you measuring the dbm level?

Comment: I don't know which dBi the antenna's are. I measure with an $100 ESI 21. https://epeconseil.fr/produit/epe-conseil-esi-21/

Comment: Unless Google translate is being goofy, the product page for that says it can read in the 50 to 8ghz range. (I'm assuming the 50 is in megahertz) the problem with using these types of frequency detectors, is that you don't actually know what is transmitting, or if it's calibration is correct. You could be picking up ham radio, radar, Doppler or millitary communication's. Try using wardriving apps, like netstumbler or similar. Depending on the antennas in the device this reading may be off by 10-15%. But it should let you know if it's actually your equipment high power bursting or not.